# Convert column from list to factor or character

Tags: r, string

I have addresses I need to compare. I got 90% of the way there thanks to a helpful answer on this site, but I need the last 10%.

I have the code below to generate addresses for comparison. I need to see if there is any difference between `addr1` and `addr2`.

```
eg_data <- data.frame(addr1 = c('123 Main St','742 Evergreen 
Ter','8435 Roanoke Dr','1340 N State Pkwy') , addr2 = c('123 
Main St Apt 4','742 Evergreen Terrace','8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 
5','1340 N State Pkwy'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next part, very helpful, is combining `vecsets` subfunction `vsetdiff` with `strsplit`, to compare the two and extract any difference

```
eg_data$addr_comp2_1 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$addr2, 
split=""), strsplit(eg_data$addr1, split=""))
```

Run the code and see, but I am left with the differences in the format like `c(" ","A","p","t"," ","4")` for difference b/t the row1 addresses, and it is in list form. I need this column to be individual rows of strings or factors. In the data view, I need to see `"addr_comp2_1 : chr "123..."` rather than `addr_comp2_1`:List of 4 , so that the dataframe itself gives me " Apt 4" in col3 / row1 and not `c(" ","A","p","t"," ","4")`.

I have tried

```
eg_data$fix <- paste(eg_data$addr_comp2_1, collapse=', ')
eg_data$fix2 <- str_c(eg_data$addr_comp2_1, collapse=',')
eg_data$fix3 <- as.factor(eg_data$addr_comp2_1)
eg_data$fix4 <- lapply(eg_data$addr_comp2_1, unlist)
eg_data$fix5 <- (matrix(unlist(eg_data$addr_comp2_1), nrow=4, 
byrow=F))
eg_data$fix6 <- unlist(eg_data$addr_comp2_1, use.names=FALSE, 
recursive=FALSE)
```

These obviously don't work. The `fix5` is close, but it gives each individual character its own row, as opposed to taking the groupings of `c()`, so I end up with 17 rows, instead of adding a single column of four.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where does the function `vsetdiff()` come from?

Comment: It's a subfunction from the vecsets package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to concatenate the results. `lapply` function will do it for you.

**Code**

```
eg_data <- data.frame(addr1 = c('123 Main St','742 Evergreen 
Ter','8435 Roanoke Dr','1340 N State Pkwy') , addr2 = c('123 
Main St Apt 4','742 Evergreen Terrace','8435 Roanoke Dr Unit 
5','1340 N State Pkwy'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

eg_data$addr_comp2_1 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$addr2,split=""), strsplit(eg_data$addr1, split=""))

eg_data$addr_comp2_2 = lapply(eg_data$addr_comp2_1, paste, collapse = '')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: OMG so close. What I *really* need is something that would, for the second row, only return to me the "race" portion of Terrace, IE only what is not in the addr1 column. If you know how to do that additional specification, you'd be my hero, but this is even closer, and I can run a simple series of gsubs to standardize addresses. If this is as close as it gets, I'll take it. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited my response. Your code was right then. You just have to add extra line which concatenates the vector.

Comment: I sweared I tried these two, in succession, and then an as.charactrer command, but apparently not, b/c this does exactly what I need. THANK YOU !